# r tryCatch how to pass object to error function

Tags: r, try-catch

```
myFunc <- function(x)
{
  x <- timeSeries(x, charvec=as.Date(index(x)))
  t<-tryCatch(  doSomething(x), error=function(x) rep(0,ncol(x))
  )
  t
}
```

How do I pass x into the error function? When I run the above I get:

Error in rep(0, ncol(x)) : invalid 'times' argument

Comment: Read the error message: it's saying `ncol(x)` is NA (or possibly NULL or less likely Inf).  You didn't say what package `timeSeries` belongs to, but I'd guess it doesn't return an object which has columns.

Answer (score 5):

The `error` argument is a handler, documented (see `?tryCatch`) to accept one argument (the error condition). The error handler has access to whatever variables were available at the time `stop` was invoked. So

```
f = function() {
    tryCatch({
        i = 1
        stop("oops")
    }, error=function(e) {
        stop(conditionMessage(e), " when 'i' was ", i)
    })
}
```

catches the error thrown by the code, discovers the value `i`, and emits a more informative message. So I'd guess

```
myFunc <- function(x)
{
    tryCatch({
        x <- timeSeries(x, charvec=as.Date(index(x)))
        doSomething(x)
    }, error=function(...) rep(0, ncol(x)))
}
```